# Defining Logged in Users Details in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I dont know how to go about defining a set of attributes to a user when they have logged in to Apex. After logging in with their username and password, the tables should display data about that User. The username and password are stored in a table with general details such as 'name','email address','home address etc' with 'Employee_id' being the primary key. When they have logged in they should have that specific row's data values. What I have tried to attempt:

I made a report want to specify the name display:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EMPLOYEE_USERNAME= :APP_USER
```

(Have tried to get the current logged in username).

This has not worked and nothing is displayed.

Comment: have you tried submitting :APP_USER?

Answer (score 0):

For your above query to return data the value of `EMPLOYEE_USERNAME` must match the current username which is stored in the `:APP_USER` variable. Please note that `:APP_USER` retrieves the username of the current user in uppercase. I suggest you change your query like this:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE UPPER(EMPLOYEE_USERNAME)= :APP_USER
```

This type of query has some performance problems i suggest adding a trigger that will ensure the `EMPLOYEE_USERNAME` is in a uppercase or add a Function Based Index on `UPPER(EMPLOYEE_USERNAME)`.